# Calculate $\int_0^1\frac{\cos(\arctan x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

When I was considering derivatives and integrals (to try integration by parts) related with a closed form for $\zeta(3)$ (due to **J. Jensen**, see the **Wikipedia**), I've asked to me

> **Question.** How it is possible to calculate $$\int_0^1\frac{\cos(\arctan x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx?$$
>   Can you justify a closed form for 
>   $$\int\frac{\cos(\arctan x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx?$$
>   **Many thanks.**

---

(The integral $\int \frac{\cos(\arctan x)}{1+\sqrt{x}}dx$ seems much more complicated).

Comment: $\cos(\arctan x) = 1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$.  But I think that still leaves an elliptic integral.

Comment: You are welcome @B.Goddard, very thanks much for the substitution. The problem is that I don't know facts about elliptic integrals.

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

Comment: Very thank much always for your answers in this site @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I:=\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\cos\arctan x}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm d x$$
$\displaystyle \cos\arctan x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, so:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x^2+1)}}\,\mathrm d x$$
Now substitute $x=\tan\frac\theta 2$:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x^2+1)}}\,\mathrm d x=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \frac{\mathrm d \theta}{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\beta \left(\frac 14,\frac 12\right)=\boxed{\frac{\Gamma ^2 \left(\frac 14 \right)}{4\sqrt\pi}}$$
This is also equal to $K\left(\frac 12\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now I study it.

Comment: I've forgot check it as the answer, I am sorry.